# SSRS: Is it possible to show aggregated values in a text box?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm developing an SSRS report. In it, I have to show an aggregated value in a text box. The aggregated value represents a concatenated string where the substrings are comming from  a dataset column. For the aggregation I'm using a custom code. 
All this works fine.
My problem is that I don't know how to represent the concatenated value in a text box. The concatinating function I'm using is invoked by RunningValue function and as far as I see it can be used only in a table and Matrix.

Comment: Can you provide us with all of the code you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your aggregated value in the table or matrix - hide it if necessary. Edit and note the name of the textbox in the table or matrix e.g. AggregatedValue.

Then in your text box you can refer to it's value using the ReportItems syntax e.g.

```
= ReportItems!AggregatedValue.Value
```